# Web services and JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, swing, jakarta-ee, jpa

We have a tick client application done in Swing using SOAP based web services for all his backend operations.  Our biggest challenge right now is in transforming the "client model object" into the JPA graph when it goes back to the services for doing the persistence.

Here is the technology stack that we are using:

Java 6
Oracle WebLogic 11g
Spring 3.0.5
Hibernate 3.6.1

I like to think that there must be proven pattern for addressing this particular problem. Please advise.

Comment: IMHO this question is too broad for SO. You just need a mapping between those objects you retrieve via the web service and your JPA entities - it's all about design.

Comment: Are you saying that the every single project with a similar setup will have to come up with its own mapping implementation?  I'm sure you do realize the challenges this imposes when you face elaborate entity relationships...

Comment: You should think about loose coupling - you have a web service interface and an internal representation of your datamodel (JPA). They may differ - and in large applications they do...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is pattern, from my experience I see DTO pattern is used largely when you have some thing transferred to client. What your service normally does it process the DTO and pass it on to DAO layer. In DAO layer you do all that transformation from DTO to your JPA entities.

Client-> Service Interface(business logic)->DAO Classes(has persistence logic)

DTO are constructed in client and service layers reads them and applies business logic and then pass it onto DAO layer.

Comment: It's about SOAP web services, so the JPA entities itself do never come into play (maybe there structure, but this is a design issue).